# How do I return an Int variable from an @IBAction function in swift 3?

Tags: swift, ibaction

I am trying to return a value that I have made in my Xcode project. The Int value is made in the @IBAction function of a stepper.

```
@IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper) -> Int {
    let Number: Int = Int(sender.value)
    return Number
print(Number)
```

The system is giving me this error: "Methods declared @IBAction must return 'Void' (not'Int')".

Comment: There's no reason to do this as you're not calling stepper directly, the system is calling it for you. Where's that return value supposed to end up?

Comment: @IBAction These are events. They shouldn't return any result

Comment: use a `var` at the class level for the View controller class like `var stepperValue: Number?` and then use that variable `stepperValue` inside the `@IBAction` method. `IBAction`s cannot return values.

Comment: It is supposed to go into a UIButton which would print a randomized number, when the max(upper) is the value of the stepper

Comment: Sure, just use `didSet` like this - `var stepperValue: Number = 0{ //use stepperValue here to set the UIButton }`

Comment: What's unclear with the error message *must return 'Void'* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@IBAction` is an inbuilt attribute used to fire methods that would perform certain tasks based on user's interaction and cannot return values/objects. What you can do is trigger other actions, or initialize other global/local variables within the action method.

The error - `Methods declared @IBAction must return 'Void' (not'Int')` simply means that an `IBAction` method cannot return anything and must return `void` aka nothing.

Based on your comment on using the stepper's value for a `UIButton` this is what you can do-

At the class level for the View Controller declare a variable

```
var stepperValue: Int = 0 {
   didSet{
      // use stepperValue with your UIButton as you want
   }
}
```

And then the `@IBAction`-

```
@IBAction func stepper(_ sender: UIStepper){
    stepperValue = Int(sender.value)
}
```

Everytime, `stepperValue` is set inside the `@IBAction` method the code block inside the `didSet` observer will fire and the `stepperValue`'s current value can be accessed inside the `didSet` observer code block to be used in any logic you want there.

OR, you could simply put the entire `didSet` observer block code inside of the `IBAction` method `stepper`.

OR, you could write another method `func modifyMyButton(_ stepperval: Int)` put your logic there and call this method from inside the `IBAction` method.

Answer (score 1):

`@IBAction func` are system based functions that are triggered on events based on user interaction. They don't return you anything. They call functions for you, if you want. You need to describe what scenario are you trying to implement.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.